# Object.hasOwn() vs Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance, hasownproperty

The new method `Object.hasOwn()` returns a boolean indicating whether the specified object has the indicated property as its own property but so does `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`, what is the difference between them and what is the benefit of using one over the other?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Using `Object.hasOwn()` as a replacement for `Object.hasOwnProperty()`**

`Object.hasOwn()` is intended as a replacement for `Object.hasOwnProperty()` and is a new method available to use (yet still not fully supported by all browsers like safari yet but soon will be)

`Object.hasOwn()` is a static method which returns true if the specified object has the specified property as its own property. If the property is inherited, or does not exist, the method returns false.

```js
const person = { name: 'John' };
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'name'));// true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'age'));// false

console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('name'));// true
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('age'));// false

const person2 = Object.create({gender: 'male'});
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person2, 'gender')); // false
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('gender')); //false
 
// gender is not an own property of person, it exist on the person2 prototype
```

So, after looking at both `Object.hasOwn()` and `Object.hasOwnProperty()` in action, they seems quite the same.. So why should we use `Object.hasOwn()` over the `Object.hasOwnProperty()`?

It is recommended to this method use over the `Object.hasOwnProperty()` because it also works for objects created by using `Object.create(null)` and for objects that have overridden the inherited `hasOwnProperty()` method. Although it's possible to solve these kind of problems by calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(<object reference>, <property name>)` on an external object, `Object.hasOwn()`  overcome these problems, hence is preferred (see examples below)

```js
let person = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  age: 35
};
 
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')); // true
console.log(person.hasOwnProperty('age')); // false
```

```js
let person = Object.create(null);
person.age = 35;
if (Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')) {
  console.log(person.age); // true - works regardless of how the object was created
}

if (person.hasOwnProperty('age')){ // throws error - person.hasOwnProperty is not a function
   console.log('hasOwnProperty' + person.age);
}
```

More about `Object.hasOwn` can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn

Browser compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility

Comment: Nice answer. Just adding a link to the [original proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-accessible-object-hasownproperty) for people (like me) who want to see even more details.

Comment: why does "console.log(Object.hasOwn(person2, 'gender'))" return false?
person2 does have the property if you inspect person2.gender?
It wasn't created with troublesome "Object.create(null)" so curious why it doesn't return true.

Comment: Because Gender is created not on the person2 object, but on it's prototype.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Adding that `hasOwn()` needs node16... if you have node-dependent 'stuff'. E.g., Postman Monitors' node version is not yet up to this version, so any Monitor test runs will fail, even though `hasOwn()` works locally. (EDIT: Thinking it's their node, since we updated node in Newman to work around this, but I digress...). So that's something to think about when choosing `hasOwn()`. Cheers.